# How to structure this editable table in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to implement a table with the following features:

- The table will have hundreds of rows
- Each row can be selected/checked
- Each row has a 'note' (pops up a modal to edit the note)
- The table will have a 'select all' button to check all the rows
- Rows can be added/removed

My initial attempt was to structure the table like this (heavily pseudocoded to be concise):

```
let [rows, setRows] = useState("rows from an api");
let [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);

const checkAllRows = () => {
  let stateRows = rows;
  stateRows.map(row => row.checked = true);
  setRows(stateRows);
}

const checkRow = (rowId) => {
  let thisRow = rows.find(row => row.rowId === rowId);
  thisRow.checked = true;
}

<button onClick={() => checkAllRows} />
<Table>
     {rows.map(row => <Row row={row} checkRow={checkRow} setShowModal={setShowModal} />}
     <NotesModal />
<Table>
```

Each row would:

```
const Row = (props) => {
  let { row, checkRow, setShowModal } = props;
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>some data</td>
      <td><button onClick={() => checkRow(row.rowId)} /></td>
      <td><button onClick={() => setShowModal(true)} /></td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

However there are a two major issues that affect rendering.

First is the `NotesModal`.  By keeping the `NotesModal` in the parent Table, I have only one modal that I can update with the selected row (save an *activeRow* in the parent tables state), however showing/hiding the modal causes the entire table to re-render because I'm setting the state of the parent table, which with hundreds of rows will be quite slow.  I could move the `NotesModal` to each row which would then only render the individual row that's selected, but then I would have hundreds of Modals in the tree - seems like it would work fine but also seems like a bad practice.

Second, checking any individual row updates the *rows* in the parent state, which then causes the entire table to re-render.  I tried using `useMemo` for each row and used the row properties as the dependents so individual rows would only re-render if they had to, but once a row was added/removed it blanked out.  The more I looked into `useMemo` the more it seemed like I was trying to hack it into a place it wasn't meant to be used.  I could potentially move the `selected` state of the row down into the Row component's state, however I don't know how I would implement the `checkAllRows` function because the `checked` state would now be down in the child component and the parent would not have direct access to it.

What's the best way to structure my state/functions to get this working without having things re-render all the time.

Comment: Does the `NotesModal` component *need* to be rendered as a child of the `Table` component? Would moving it up to the parent component and rendering a sibling work for you?

Comment: "The more I looked into useMemo the more it seemed like I was trying to hack it into a place it wasn't meant to be used." Yeah, I think you want to check `React.memo` instead.

Comment: @DrewReese I could move the NotesModal up, but let's say I move it up to <TableWrapper /> it would still cause <TableWrapper /> to re-render which would then re-render <Table /> anyway, wouldn't it?

Comment: By default, yes, but there are methods of memoizing the rendered result of the `Table` component so it won't needlessly rerender.

Comment: @DrewReese Hmm, alright I think that gives me something to go on.